# The meaning of and difference between ～を中心に and ～をめぐって

Tags: grammar, word-choice, jlpt

What is the meaning of and difference between `～を中心に` and `～をめぐって`?

Space ALC defines [`～を中心に`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%82%92%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AB/UTF-8/) as "with a focus on" and [`～をめぐって`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%82%92%E3%82%81%E3%81%90%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/UTF-8/) as "centering on", but I'm having trouble figuring out the meaning and difference in usage of the two.

---

I saw the following example sentence for `～を中心に` in the (old) JLPT2 `完全マスター`, which [JGram](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=wochuushinni) interpreted slightly differently to me:

> 駅**を中心に**沢山の商店が集まっている。
>
> - My first interpretation: "*In* the station there are lots of stores grouped together."
> - JGram's interpretation (which I now think is more accurate): "*Centered around* the station there are many stores."

The way I now understand it is that `～を中心に` means more "([focused/centered/revolving]) *around*" rather than "*in* the center of something". Would this explanation be accurate?

---

I've also encountered `～をめぐって` a couple of times. The following example I read today in the April 2012 edition of `中央公論`:

> 政党というものは、単に選挙**をめぐって**候補者をリクルートし、有権者へ働きかけて動員するための組織ではない。
>   My attempted translation: "A political party isn't an organization which is simply about recruiting candidates *focusing on* elections and encouraging mobilization of voters."

If I switched `をめぐって` with `を中心に`, would it have the same or similar meaning? What would the differences in nuance be between the two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have pretty much different meanings. `中心に` adds blur. It means `centered around`. `めぐって` means 'regarding', and implies some kind of a debate. They are in general not interchangable.

> 駅を中心に沢山の商店が集まっている
>   'many stores are gathered around the the station'
>   More literally: 'many stores are gathered with its center being the station'
>
> 駅をめぐって沢山の商店が集まっている
>   'many store (owner)s are gathered {regarding, to talk about} the station'
>
> 選挙(の時期)を中心に候補者をリクルートする
>   'hire candidates mostly at around the time of an election'
>   More literally: 'hire candidates with its center being the time of an election'
>
> 選挙をめぐって候補者をリクルートする
>   'hire candidates {regarding, for} an election'

Answer (score 7):

In additions to what @sawa said, I think it's easy to keep straight if you remember the verb `めぐる` has the meanings of "going around" or "surrounding".  Thus, `～をめぐって／～をめぐり／～をめぐる` usually has at least a slight negative meaning (as @sawa stated) usually about some debate, controversy, etc.

Here are a couple examples.  (I'm going to expand on one of @sawa's because I feel it's a little too vague to be helpful to you -- no offense to @sawa).

> - 駅の改築**をめぐって**近くの店主がたくさん集まってデモる。　→　Many of the nearby store owners will gather and protest the reconstruction of the station (protest surrounding the reconstruction of the station
> - 大統領の経済政策**をめぐり**色々な対立する意見があります。　→　There are many opposing opinions surrounding/concerning the President's economic policies.
> - 資源の利用**をめぐる**争いがようやく解決に向かった。　→　The dispute about/surrounding the resource usage is finally headed toward a solution.

As far as the sentence you provided, the controversy is that there are obviously some people who hold the opinion that a political parties only exist to get the upper hand in an election (by doing the things listed), instead of focusing on meeting the peoples' needs.

Answer (score 3):

を中心に:  focusing primarily on

Example usage:

> we discussed life at school, the main point of the discussion being the well-being of students.
>
> > 生徒の福祉を中心に、学生の日常生活を議論した。

をめぐって: discussing something/about (often to show the motivation of the debate/argument/fight)

Example usage:

> They fought with one another for this girl.
>
> > 彼女をめぐって喧嘩した。

If you remember that the fight for the girl (or boy, whatever) is a typical use of めぐって, you should confidently be able to use/understand it properly.