# Is を[noun]に, as in を条件に, a common construct?

Tags: grammar

I was a little confused by the following sentence because 条件 is a regular noun, but looking at examples I see that it means "on the condition of [object]": `財政危機におちいっているギリシャは、 緊縮を条件に、ヨーロッパのほかの国から支援を受けています`

I'm wondering, was there a verb that just isn't said anymore?

And I'm trying to think of other example constructs like it, but haven't come up with anything. Is this a common construct?

Comment: I think it's a contraction of 緊縮を条件に `して`, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same construct can be used with other nouns (but not every noun):

- 緊縮**を条件に**支援を受ける to receive aid on the condition of austerity
- 結婚**を前提に**交際する to go out with a person seriously with the idea of getting married
- 利用者の意見**を参考に**使い勝手を改善する to improve usability taking the feedback from users into account
- 駅**を中心に**たくさんの商店が集まっている。 Centered around the station there are many stores. (This example is based on an example in “[The meaning of and difference between ～を中心に and ～をめぐって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/the-meaning-of-and-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AB-and-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E3%82%81%E3%81%90%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6)” by cypher.)

In these examples, as istrasci wrote in a comment on the question, we could insert して after に.  (I do not know if the version with して is the original form and the version without して is a contraction of it or not.)  However, in the following similar-looking examples, this is not the case, so I am not sure if this captures the essence of the construct:

- 来月中旬**を[目処]{めど}に**この仕事を終わらせます。 I will finish this work by about the middle of next month. (This example is based on an example in [Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%81%E3%81%A9&stype=0&dtype=3&dname=2na).)
- オリンピック**を最後に**引退する to retire with the Olympic Games as the last event