# Japanese 受け身 and sentences

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words

> 批評された側では、多少、けなされていても、褒められたところをよりどころにして希望をつなぎとめることができる。

-> people who was criticized, and humiliated, 
The things that was praised, よりどころ (become foundation(?)) 希望をつなぎとめる(fasten hope(?))

And I wonder why けなされていても followed by 褒められたところ?? Its two different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vocabulary:

- AをBに（して）: with A as B; using A as B (See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5615/5010))
- [よりどころ](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D) (noun): (lit. "place to rely on") thing one can believe in; (mental) crutch; supporter
- 希望をつなぎとめる: (lit. "anchor hope") keep having whatever small hope

The main structure of the sentence:

> 批評された側では、希望をつなぎとめることができる。
>   The side (=person) which was criticized (i.e., the author of the work) can still have small hope.

And the followings are two subordinate clauses that each modify the verb つなぎとめる:

> - 多少けなされていても
>     even if (his work) is spoken ill a bit
> - 褒められたところをよりどころにして
>     using the part which was praised as a crutch

The whole sentence roughly means "(If there are parts that were praised in your work,) Even when some parts of your work are spoken ill of, you can still have some hope using the praised part as a crutch."

Comment: Sometimes when i read japanese sentences, i dont even get the point of the sentence. How to differentiate what kind of clause it is? And do you always link the first part in sentence to the last part like this->批評された側では、希望をつなぎとめることができる。? Or are there any tricks to understand japanese sentences? For example on the exam we cant search in dictionary the meaning of けなす、よりどころ、つなぎとめる , do you still can get the point of the sentence without knowing the meaning of some words? By maybe judging from the structure of the sentence?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono In this sentence, the subject (批評された側) and the corresponding verb (つなぎとめる) are far from each other, but that happens often in (written) English, too. English writers use [parenthetical phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_(rhetoric)) a lot, some of which can be extremely long. But we can still somehow feel "I saw the subject, but the corresponding verb has not arrived yet", can't we? Practice makes perfect.